# Starting new journal?

Tags: publications

I want to start my own journal; the area would be in the applications of novel psychoactive substances.

Does anyone have any experience in this eg web based or paper etc?

Comment: Also see [How do I start a new peer-reviewed open access journal?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/how-do-i-start-a-new-peer-reviewed-open-access-journal) and [How to create an editorial board for a new journal](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62670/how-to-create-an-editorial-board-for-a-new-journal)

Comment: Also, don't start a journal.

Comment: It concerns me that I keep seeing these kinds of questions.